# Fix partition alignment in FreeBSD

Tags: partition, freebsd

I'm working on a FreeBSD 8.x (pfSense 2.1) system and post-install, realised that the partition is misaligned to the disk (starts at sector offset 63). GParted doesn't recognise UFS so that is out.

I've had a quick look at `sade`, `fdisk`, and `gpart` but can't work out how to non-destructively move the partition; is there an easy way to do so or should I simply dump out the config & rebuild?

Answer (score 1):

`gpart` is the best one. There you have the parameter on gpart add `-a 4K` for example. By `-a` gives alignment and 4K you should use as a parameter for alignment, because the most new disks are working with 4K sectors. Even on old disks it has a reason, just to getting used to 4K.